# How to print the square brackets in the output in SAS

Tags: sas

I'm trying to print the following dataset which contains only 1 line of charcters:
[HEADER]

```
 DATA TEST1;              
    INPUT SSN $10.;       
    DATALINES;            
 [HEADER]                 
 RUN;
```

However the output I got is ÝHEADER. Can someone point out why this happened?

Comment: it works for me with no problems.  I'm on SAS 9.4 with `ENCODING=WLATIN1`

Comment: Sometimes this is to do with the option `FORMCHAR=`: http://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/lrdict/64316/HTML/default/viewer.htm#a000279104.htm

Comment: Works for me as well!!,  you can try concatenating [] after reading HEADER.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe you are using SAS on Mainframe environment. if yes, then the issue is with the mainframe codepage on the emulator host settings. Check the following linke to know more about the issue on square brackets on mainframe : http://x3270.bgp.nu/Brackets.html